# When would there be multiple SKUs from Purchase.getSkus() when using BillingClient 4?

Tags: android, android-billing

I am upgrading from BillingClient 3 to 4 as is required by Google now. In this change, there is a removal of the Product.getSku() and you are now supposed to use getSkus(). My question is, when will this be populated with more or less than one? It seems like each item only has one SKUs? Is this only used if you select and allow multi-quantity purchases? Is there some way that the user can force a bundle if my UI is not designed for it? Would it be safe to just use

```
product.getSkus().get(0)
```

and use it as it was before?

Comment: Hey! What conclusion did you come to ? I'm also wondering in what case the array will have more than 1 item in it.

Comment: @AndreiBogdan - I never got a clear answer. There is the option to add multiple quantities of an item in checkout which we left off. Even then, there is a quantity field so it makes no sense. The only thing I can figure is they must be preparing for bundle products of some type. I just risked it and left the code as seen above as I could see no case where the first SKU was not the one I was looking for, let alone there being more than one SKU